Parse a pretty-printed string representation of a DataFrame back into a Polars DataFrame?
I have a string representation of a DataFrame:
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ alpha ┆ beta │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i32   ┆ i32  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1    │
│ 1     ┆ 0    │
│ 2     ┆ 0    │
└───────┴──────┘

Is there any existing functionality in Polars to parse this back into a DataFrame?

.from_repr()
df = pl.from_repr("""
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ alpha ┆ beta │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i32   ┆ i32  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1    │
│ 1     ┆ 0    │
│ 2     ┆ 0    │
└───────┴──────┘
""")

